# How do I dodge the Phantom Egg's teleporting hand attack?

Tags: sonic-mania

In Titanic Monarch Act 2, the Phantom Egg boss has an attack with two red holographic hands that teleport you to a different room if they catch you.

No matter how long I try avoiding his attack, it always seem to catch me. I've even tried letting the hands catch Tails instead, but that leaves a second hand that won't stop chasing me.

**How do I dodge the Phantom Egg's teleporting hand attack? Is it even possible?**

[image: Phantom Egg's teleporting hand attack]
<sub>-[Gif source: BeardBear](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=orfWhy3jcpA)</sub>

Comment: "I've even tried letting the hands catch Tails instead" Damn dude, that's cold

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, no it's not possible. I've tried a bunch of things, and I've never seen a video of it being done.

In fact, usually I jump directly into the hands because at least one of the mini-boss levels contains rings, and they're all pretty easy to avoid once you know their pattern.

Comment: The ball and cup switch miniboss is the one that gets me every time. Always been bad at that one

Comment: I was hoping that turning on & Knuckles Mode when you play with Sonic and Tails might work (by giving you three characters), but it looks like Tails get dropped at the start of the game when you try this.